# Managing submenus on Bootstrap 4 mobile menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am porting our BS 3.3.7 site to 4.  We have a header with a nav in it, some items are dropdown items (menus).

[image]

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white bg-pb-header-gradient">
    <button class="navbar-toggler p-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="" routerLink="/home">
      <img src="/assets/images/pb-header-mark.svg" width="32" height="31" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> Design System
    </a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
    </li>
    ... etc ...
```

I am trying to get this to work on Mobile with a minimum of overrides.  First thing I noticed is that the top-level items (here "Home" "Fundamentals" and "Web") are part of the header, so I had to set a background-size for the gradient so the "menu" wouldn't have a gradient background:

[image]

Fine but now the Drop-down menu under "web" is styled like a dropdown:

[image]

Is there no built-in override for this?  It sure seems like this is a very common pattern for header menus that have to go into a mobile menu.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behavior, as you can see if you resize your browser to mobile size on the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content

If you want to change this, you'll need custom styling, using CSS media queries.